# Rules on lone hands

Tags: euchre

In euchre what, if any, is the penalty if a loners partner plays a card ? I went alone, the opponent to my left lead a card and my partner played the same suite as led.

Answer (score 3):

In a friendly game, where the extra card didn't give any important information (such as playing an ace that the bidder would otherwise not have known where it was), I'd just pick it up and continue play.

Tournament rules should have something to cover this scenario, but a reasonable penalty in this case seems to be forcing the bidder to play with their partner rather than alone.

Comment: This solution was the solution we used when we had high school tournaments years ago.  The partnership loses the opportunity for four points.